# facebook send API Error Code: 100 API Error Description: Invalid parameter Error Message: 'link' is invalid

Tags: facebook, send

I am using facebook post GRAPH UI for posting private message with link to my application in facebook.
Earlier it was working fine but from last two days the dialog started throwing error as :

> An error occurred. Please try again later.
>
> API Error Code: 100
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>   Error Message: 'link' is invalid.

for sending message I am using code :

```
function sendMessage(id) {
  FB.ui({
    method : 'send',
    name : 'My APP',
    link : 'https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP/',
    to : id,
    show_error : 'true',
    description : 'my description'
  });
}
```

I have Googled about this and only relevant information I get is that facebook is blocking the link to its own domain as to avoid spam.
 as I change the link to other live site its working.

I need to send link to my application as I have to provide such functionality.

Comment: If anybody testing in local with url like http://localhost:3000, http://127.0.0.1:300. This error will come. But it will work without any problem in live url.

Comment: check my answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539659/avoiding-error-100-invalid-parameter-requires-valid-redirect-uri-in-applicati/34068735#34068735

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

#### [Facebook Send Dialog Error Code: 100 API Error Description: Invalid parameter Error Message: ‘link’ is invalid.](http://blog.w3villa.com/programming/facebook-send-dialog-error-code-100-api-error-description-invalid-parameter-error-message-link-is-invalid/)

---

**Problem Cause:**

Facebook is not allowing to use its own link as to stop spamming.

**Problem Solution:**

There is as such no solution as its bared by Facebook API.

**Other workout:**

Shorten URL, but its didn’t works as Facebook check the provided URL.
Redirect URL, same as above.
In my case I have deployed an additional HTML page just use to redirect to the Facebook App link.
Just remember that you should have a timer for few seconds as Facebook scans the provided URL, so it wont be able to detect that the page is redirecting to same Application Link.
I have used the following code for my HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "https://apps.facebook.com/MY_APPLICATION_ID";
    var myVar = setInterval(function() {
        myTimer()
    }, 1000);
    var counter = 3;
    function myTimer() {
        if (counter == 0) {
            window.location.replace(url);
            window.clearInterval(myVar);
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "you will be redirected in "
                + counter + " seconds...";
        counter = counter - 1;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: check my answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539659/avoiding-error-100-invalid-parameter-requires-valid-redirect-uri-in-applicati/34068735#34068735

Answer (score 6):

I've had similar issues, and figured I'd share the results of my investigation here.

The only information in the Facebook documentation describing the `link` parameter is not terribly helpful:

> **link** -The URL that is being sent in the message.

#### There are a couple other StackOverflow questions similar / related to this one:

#### [Facebook API Error 100 - invalid link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830066/facebook-api-error-100-invalid-link)

> this problem ended up being a malformed `picture` parameter

#### [Facebook FB.ui send dialog intermittently returns invalid link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982183/facebook-fb-ui-send-dialog-intermittently-returns-invalid-link-error/18055274#18055274) -

> "The issue revolved around our url being dynamic and needing force caching each time. I now make an ajax call to "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object" to refresh it and then launch the send dialog."

### I still don't know *precisely* what constitutes a valid `link` parameter, but...

Making some inferences from the above questions & responses, as well as some testing on my part, valid `link` parameters:

- Must be "fully qualified". I.E. containing `http://` or `https://`
- Must **not** be `facebook.com` links
- Might not like redirects (or you have to be sneaky with them)
- *Do* support URLs not in the "App Domains" list
- *Do* support Query Strings
- May be finicky regarding dynamically generated pages (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982183/facebook-fb-ui-send-dialog-intermittently-returns-invalid-link-error/18055274#18055274))

Apparently Facebook has some sort of link crawling mechanism that performs some unknown tests on a `link` parameter to determine its validity. I only wish they would choose to document it for us.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem except that my link was pointing to my website.

In case someone is in a similar scenario please check at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982183/facebook-fb-ui-send-message-dialog-intermittently-returns-invalid-link-error/18055274#18055274). Hope that will help some people.

Answer (score -1):

If bad parameter occurs and and message reads "API Error Code: 100" - Make sure the box beside "Share with playlist starting from" is unchecked in youtube and that error won't show.