# How to get Facebook share link owner?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Previously Facebook allowed to share anything you want, now we should use feed and send dialogs. When we are using dialogs to share link to friend, then link should be validated though Facebook (as I remember even without sub domains).
Is there a way to add parameter to link like ?ref_id=any_unique_value or other ways, later sever to determine, with whom the link belongs to (and whom to reward).

Comment: It's difficult to parse what you're asking here, but you should be able to add a query string (`?ref_id=abcd`) to the `link` parameter of a `FB.ui` "send". Where are you having problems?

Comment: @ZachL you should add it as answer, as it seems that it's exactly what OP was asking :)

Comment: I missed something, feed dialog is ok with any link you give it, problem appears with other dialogs, + there exist a /share.php service.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be able to add a query string (`?ref_id=abcd`) to the link parameter of a `FB.ui` "send".

The `FB.ui` *can* be a bit finicky with what `link`s it accepts. Please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234295/363701) for more info on valid links.